# What is controlling the radio buttons in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

Take this code for Example

```
<form>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" checked>Male
<br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
</form>
```

It allows a user to select one button at a time, I was always under the impression that javascript was the answer to this type of a solution. So my question is, is there any embedded javascript in the HTML radio button and if not, where is the function coming from?

Comment: Don't Ask Very Silly Questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its the Browser's duty to do that for us.

Why?

Because the behavior is stated in the spec:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html/forms.html#radio-button-state-(type=radio)